# Anything wrong with storing studio monitors right next to each other?

Tags: home-studio, monitors, studio-monitors, loudspeakers, storage

I have to take apart my studio equipment and store it elsewhere while some construction takes place in the studio. I wanted to ask whether there was anything wrong in storing my two Yamaha HS8 studio monitors right next to each other for a few days.  The speakers wouldn’t be in their boxes.  I didn’t know whether that would lead to degaussing of the magnets or any other bad effects, and whether it was better to store them some distance apart. I wouldn’t think so, but thought to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be no effect whatsoever.

Permanent magnets cannot be de-gaussed, they're permanent. Nothing else within a speaker will be affected.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what’s a permanent magnet?

Comment: @Cerulean According to Wikipedia: "Permanent magnets are made from "hard" ferromagnetic materials such as alnico and ferrite that are subjected to special processing in a strong magnetic field during manufacture to align their internal microcrystalline structure, making them very hard to demagnetize." If you think about it, speaker magnets are stored very close to each other all the time and speakers still work. Many speaker enclosures have multiple magnets inside the same enclosure.

Comment: _ferro_ means Iron (well, _contains_ iron)